# mssql_fetch_object is not receiving all data from a sql procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this procedure in sql:

```
    USE [FINANZAS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [eva].[reporte_historial_metas]    Script Date: 11/06/2017 17:03:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [eva].[reporte_historial_competencias]

    @mper_rut int,  
    @mper_dv  varchar(1),
    @eper_anho_periodo int,
    @eper_codigo_periodo int 

AS
BEGIN


declare @script varchar(max),
        @script2 varchar(max),
        @max    int,
        @contador int

SELECT  @max = COUNT(1)
FROM  finanzas.eva.evaluacion_detalle t1 
where   t1.mper_rut = @mper_rut and 
        t1.mper_dv = @mper_dv and 
        t1.eper_codigo_periodo = @eper_codigo_periodo and 
        t1.eper_anho_periodo = @eper_anho_periodo 

select @contador = 0,
@script = ''


WHILE   @contador  <= @max 

                     BEGIN 
                 SELECT @script =@script +'<hr nobr="true"><br><br><table  style="width:100%" border="1" nobr="true"> <tr nobr="true"><td width="30%" nobr="true"><label><b>Indicador: </b></label></td><td nobr="true" width="70%">'+ t1.edet_pregunta_detalle+'</td></tr><tr nobr="true"><td width="30%" nobr="true"><label><b>Observación: </b></label></td><td nobr="true" width="70%">'+ t1.edet_observacion_detalle +'</td></tr><tr nobr="true"><td width="30%" nobr="true"><label><b>% Nota: </b></label></td><td nobr="true" width="70%">'+convert(varchar,convert(int,ROUND(t1.edet_nota_detalle,0)))+'</td></tr><tr nobr="true"><td width="30%" nobr="true"><label><b>Competencia: </b></label></td><td nobr="true" width="70%">'+ t7.ecom_descripcion_competencia +'</td></tr></table><br>'


                 FROM finanzas.eva.evaluacion_detalle t1 left join  
                      finanzas.eva.calificacion_parametro t2 on 

                          t2.cpar_codigo_parametro = t1.cpar_codigo_parametro and
                          t2.eper_anho_periodo = t1.eper_anho_periodo and
                          t2.eper_codigo_periodo = t1.eper_codigo_periodo and
                          t2.eper_fecha_inicio_periodo = t1.eper_fecha_inicio_periodo and
                          t2.eper_fecha_termino_periodo = t1.eper_fecha_termino_periodo and 
                          t2.etip_codigo_evaluacion_tipo = t1.etip_codigo_evaluacion_tipo and 
                          t2.cali_codigo_calificacion = t1.cali_codigo_calificacion,
                          finanzas.eva.evaluacion t3,
                          FINANZAS..vista_pay_datos_funcionarios t4,
                          FINANZAS..vista_pay_datos_funcionarios t5,
                          finanzas.eva.evaluados t6,
                          finanzas.eva.evaluacion_competencias t7 


                  WHERE                               t1.mper_rut = @mper_rut and
                                                      t1.mper_dv =  @mper_dv and 
                                                      t1.eper_codigo_periodo = @eper_codigo_periodo and 
                                                      t1.eper_anho_periodo = @eper_anho_periodo and
                                                      t1.edet_correlativo_detalle = @contador and 
                                                      t3.cali_codigo_calificacion = t1.cali_codigo_calificacion and
                                                      t3.eper_anho_periodo = t1.eper_anho_periodo and
                                                      t3.eper_codigo_periodo = t1.eper_codigo_periodo and
                                                      t3.eper_fecha_inicio_periodo = t1.eper_fecha_inicio_periodo and
                                                      t3.eper_fecha_termino_periodo = t1.eper_fecha_termino_periodo and
                                                      t3.etip_codigo_evaluacion_tipo = t1.etip_codigo_evaluacion_tipo and
                                                      t3.mper_rut = t1.mper_rut and 
                                                      t3.mper_dv = t1.mper_dv and
                                                      t1.etip_codigo_evaluacion_tipo = 2 and
                                                      t3.mper_rut = t6.mper_rut and
                                                      t3.mper_dv = t6.mper_dv and
                                                      t4.mper_rut = t6.mper_rut and
                                                      t4.mper_dv = t6.mper_dv and
                                                      t5.mper_rut = t6.mper_rut_evaluador and
                                                      t5.mper_dv = t6.mper_dv_evaluador and 
                                                      t7.ecom_codigo_competencia = t1.ecom_codigo_competencia and
                                                      t7.etip_codigo_evaluacion_tipo = t1.etip_codigo_evaluacion_tipo  and
                                                      t7.ecom_activo_competencia = 'S'

                                                      order by t1.edet_pregunta_detalle

                                                      select @contador = @contador+1
end

select rtrim(ltrim(@script)) as competencias

END
```

In php I have this code where I call the procedure:

```
$SQL_competencias  =  "exec finanzas.eva.reporte_historial_competencias ".$mper_rut.",'".$mper_dig_v."',".$anho.",".$codigo_periodo."";


$RESP_competencias = mssql_query($SQL_competencias, $link);
$row_competencias = mssql_fetch_object($RESP_competencias);
```

I used a printr:

```
print_r($row_competencias);
exit();
```

And display this:

[IMAGE_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVwDr.jpg)

This is the result when I execute the query in sql and the area in red is the only one that is displayed:

[IMAGE_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l34dL.jpg)

So , I need display all

any advice and help is appreciated

Sorry by my english

Comment: Yikes that query is really challenging. You have a mismatch of ANSI-92 and ANSI-89 style joins. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Add to that a bad habit with alias names (https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) and you have a recipe for a very challenging query.

Comment: Last but not least is this is vulnerable to sql injection. You should be using parameters here instead of building up a string and executing it. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: ty but why only displayed a part and not all? I can't understand that

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "displayed a part and not all".

Comment: Example: sql returns ( a , b , c , d , e) and in the screen I can only see a , b and c . But the problem maybe is with the size. IMAGE_2 =  ( a , b , c , d , e) IMAGE_1 = ( a , b and c )

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me at all. I would urge you to read what you have posted and ask yourself if you think you would be able to provide an answer on such a vague post.

Comment: What, nobody's mentioned that mssql_anything has been deprecated for years and doesn't even exist in the last 2 releases of PHP? Consider it mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your SP you embeded html tags. I guess that the retrieve result does not display anything.
For decode the html tags, try this:

```
$htmlDecode= utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($row_competencias));
print_r($htmlDecode);
```

Comment: ty, but I can display the results without any problem. The problem is that is not displaying all the results, I only use a printr to display data more clearly

Comment: Did you execute your SP directly on Managment Studio? First be sure if the data retrieve well at this point.